# Change mysql query to laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM Appraisal_skills WHERE INSTR(`assigned_to`, 6);
```

Which working well.I want to change this to laravel

I tried

```
$getskillset=Db::table('Appraisal_skills')->where(`assigned_to`, 6)->instr()->get();
```

> But got an error like BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2508:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::instr()

Please correct me.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Laravels database query builder doesn't have **instr** method. But you can use **whereRaw** method.

So your code will be like this

```
$getskillset=Db::table('Appraisal_skills')->whereRaw('INSTR(`assigned_to`, ?)', [6])->get();
```

You can read more about raw expressions in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)

and here is [api documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw)